# move-beginning-of-line broken in comint mode

Tags: debugging, comint

After a while running emacs (typically days) all comint buffers start to behave strangely (shell, python, SQL).  The ones I have already opened and the new ones that I open.

When I am after prompt, C-a moves tho the beginning of the line, as opposed to right after the prompt.  More irritating is the fact that in this state C-up (`comint-previous-input`) moves to the beggining of the line before inserting the previous input, leaving the line broken (the text is before the prompt).

A workaround for the second problem is to do `(setq comint-use-prompt-regexp t)`, but the first problem remains.

That was happening with emacs 24.3 in GNU Linux (cassou ppa for Ubuntu 12.04) and happens also now with emacs 24.4 (compiled by myself).

I debugged the shipped comint.el and tracked the issue to the built-in function `line-beginning-position`; in freshly started emacs sessions that function works fine in comint mode.  After a while this function just returns the point at the beggining of line (just like comint-mode were not enabled).

I suspect it has something to do with my setup, since google did not came up with any help.  However, binary search is not an option since I would need to spend days with a half functional emacs while waiting for the problem to happen.

Any ideas about how to narrow the suspects or further debug the problem?

Comment: Did you check `inhibit-field-text-motion`?

Comment: Yes, that variable is as it should be (and I tried toggling it, but no difference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of days without incident, I am not 100% sure but I am pretty confident that the problem was related to fixmee-mode (or the library that mode uses underneath: button-lock-mode).

I removed them from my setup and no more issues. IIRC those libraries made other emacs packages (like `wdired`, `dired-efap`) that worked with text properties in the buffer to have "glitches".

Answer (score 0):

Try to reproduce the problem without using your init file: `emacs -Q`, loading anything you need explicitly, and keeping track of all that you do.

If you can repro the problem that way, then report this as a bug: `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

If you cannot, then recursively bisect your init file, to find out what the culprit code is. You can do that by commenting out blocks of code there, using command `comment-region` (you can uncomment a selection by giving that command a plain prefix arg, `C-u`).

Comment: The problem with bisecting is what I commented in the question: problem is not evident until after some time has happened (last time it was 2 days).  I don't know what triggers the problem, because "emacs -Q" works as good as "emacs" in the 10 first minutes.  Also, my .emacs is huge and living with half of it commented out for several days while I decide if the problem will appear or not is worse than the problem.

Comment: Try `debug-on-entry` for the `C-a` command, when the problem occurs (after loading the *.el, not *.elc, defining that command), to see just what is happening. That may give a clue as to why.

Comment: Everything goes smoothly until `line-beginning-position` is called (and that is C source code).  Then that function returns the wrong value (the real line beginning position).

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, providing a clear recipe, preferably one that starts from `emacs -Q`.